# Could I get in trouble for quickly upvoting multiple posts?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, serial-voting

I was on a computer that for security reasons I didn't want to log in to the site. while I was offline, I made a list with links of things I want to upvote (around 13 links).

But before doing something that could put my account in risk, I want to ask here first.

Do you think I could get in trouble for quickly upvoting these 13 questions/answers rapidly in a short lapse of time?

Comment: If the posts are from the same person, yes, you will get in trouble.

Comment: @YannisRizos no they aren't, it is a list that took me hours to make from very different posts

Comment: Then I'd say you're fine. I've done it more than once, for more or less the same reason as you (public wifi paranoia). Just don't make a habit of it, it's a weird voting pattern.

Comment: @Yannis, care to explain or provide some references? (I've not heard of people getting into trouble for a one-time serial upvoting of another user, even though such votes will probably be automatically reverted after some time. If there are penalties, then [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857) might need some updating.)

Comment: @Arjan Hm... did you read that? "If it continues to happen between two certain IP addresses (voting each other up) or from a single user, or **looks just plain suspicious in general**, moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter and **disciplinary action may be taken against the users involved with the fraud.**" - Not that every case of serial voting is fraud, but in general it's something to avoid.

Comment: Yes, @Yannis, but I'd (also) put the emphasis on different words: "Voting fraud is when a single user **continually** upvotes many of your posts", "If **it continues to happen**" and "**may** be taken". I never heard of users getting penalized for a single, or a few, serial upvotes of a single other user. (But I surely might be wrong. And you're right: in general it should be avoided.)

Comment: @Robert Harvey 'too localized'? in less than 5 minutes I found another guy who makes the same thing, please reconsider reopening :(

Comment: So are you saying it's a duplicate then, @ajax? (I did vote to reopen, but maybe I was wrong there.)

Comment: @Arjan no, the [Yannis Rizos comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132665/could-i-get-in-trouble-for-quickly-upvoting-multiple-posts#comment367286_132665) in this post

Comment: @Arjan Well, you can't expect to hear about these things now, can you? It's something that's between the user and the moderators, unless the user brings it up on Meta, you won't hear about it. Of course it's a per case thing, and if it's a one time thing there are a few other factors to consider, but _in general_ avoid it. You should avoid it because you should be voting on content not people, not for fear of penalty.

Comment: @ajax333221 Yes, I know, my comment was in response to Arjan, not you. I already told you that there's [nothing to worry about in what you're doing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132665/could-i-get-in-trouble-for-quickly-upvoting-multiple-posts#comment367286_132665). Just don't make a habit of it, because it looks weird, people looking at the database see the pattern, but have absolutely no way of knowing anything else but the pattern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, casting votes on multiple posts is only considered serial voting when it is directed *at a specific person or group of people (such as friends or coworkers).*

If you made a list of posts that you want to upvote, but they are scattered across several unrelated users, it most likely won't hit our radar, even if the votes are temporally close (cast in a small time period).